# Can't access session variable in a different file in PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, session

I'm trying a simple login system, I'm using PHP 5.3.8. First I have a db.php file that connects to the database:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "xxx";
$pass = "xxx";
$db = "moviedb";

$connection = pg_connect ("host=$host dbname=$db user=$user
password=$pass");
if (!$connection)
{
    die("Could not open connection to database server");
}

?>
```

Using a form page the user submit username and password. I use this file to check the credentials:

```
<?php
session_start();

include("db.php");

$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];


$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=pg_query($sql);

$count=pg_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
    $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
    echo $_SESSION['username'];
    header("location:homepage.php");
}
else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";

}

?>
```

If the username and password are in the database the login is succesful and the user is redirected to this page:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("db.php");
echo $_SESSION['username'];
echo session_id();
?>

<p>WELCOME!</p>
```

The problem is the content of the session at index 'username' must be printed but instead I get an error : "Undefined index: username". I've tried everything and the code looks right I'm at my wits end for sure. Why is this not working?

Here's my form :

```
<form action="checklogin.php" method="post">
    <label>UserName :</label>
    <input type="text" name="myusername"/><br />
    <label>Password :</label>
    <input type="password" name="mypassword"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value=" Submit "/><br />
</form>
```

Comment: Set session at the below of the session_start and check if it is worked then your $count is not getting equal to 1

Comment: If $count is not set to 1 it prints "Wrong Username and Password" so I'm sure $count is 1.

Comment: just print session and put die where you are setting session username and see what is showing in session username

Comment: I honestly don't understand. Set session to what? Print where

Comment: after this line : $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername; print_r session and die(); to see actually your session variable is set or not

Comment: well there's the echo line there just doing the exact same thing. it's actually a left over from debugging since to see it you'd need to comment header line. No, $myusername isn't blank

Answer (score 0):

First of all this won't work

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
echo $_SESSION['username'];
header("location:homepage.php");
```

Because you're outputting stuff and after that you're sending a header.

What does the page output if you do

```
 print_r($_SESSION);
```

Comment: I know, it's a left over from debugging. Print_r prints out "Array()"

Comment: Okay, is $myusername set, are you sure the post value is sent to the form page.
Second, create a new php file and just put this in it
<?php
$_SESSION['username'] = 'debug';
?>
And then output the session again with print_r($_SESSION);

Comment: Yes I tried putting in a constant string instead of $myusername, doesn't change anything. I tried your suggestion, print_r outputs the content correctly.

Comment: Try to do
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
$_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
}
else{
echo 'error';
}

Answer (score -1):

I think the code for Session registration is fine.
The variable $myusername contains no value thats why session is not created and you are getting undefined index error.
Check if you are getting value from the FORM $_POST['myusername'].

```
$_SESSION['username'] = "testing";
```

Now try to print